# Why do emtrends and summary(model) provide different coefficients for a linear effect?

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, lsmeans, marginal-effect

Let's say we run a model with a three-way interaction that includes a quadratic term with its associated linear term:

```
library(emmeans)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

car_data <- mtcars[,c("mpg" , "vs" , "am" , "disp")]
car_data$vs <- as.factor(car_data$vs)
car_data$am <- as.factor(car_data$am)

model <- lm(mpg ~ vs * am * disp + vs * am * I(disp^2), data=car_data)
```

And then we calculate the response (mpg) for disp = 100 based on the summary output of the model:

```
intercept_method1 = data.frame(coef(model))[1,]
coef1_method1 = data.frame(coef(model))[4,]
coef2_method1 = data.frame(coef(model))[5,]

x = 100
mpg_x100__method1 = intercept_method1 + coef1_method1 * x + coef2_method1 *x^2 # 0.85
```

Then we learn mpg is around 0.85. Now I tried to do the same in emtrends (as I am actually interested in obtaining SEs or CIs). I calculated mpg at dist=100 as follows:

```
intercept_method2 = data.frame(emmeans(model, c("vs", "am", "disp"), 
                               at = list(vs="0", am="0", disp = 0)))$emmean

trends <- emtrends(model, ~ vs * am, var = "disp", max.degree=2)
df_trends <- data.frame(summary(trends))

coef1_method2  = subset(df_trends, vs == "0" & am == "0" & degree == "linear")$disp.trend
coef2_method2 = subset(df_trends, vs == "0" & am == "0" & degree == "quadratic")$disp.trend

mpg_x100__method2 = intercept_method2 + coef1_method2 * x + coef2_method2 *x^2 # -12.44307
```

This yields -12.5 for mpg, which is very different from 0.85. The descrepancy comes from the difference in coef1 (the linear coefficient), as coef2 and the intercept are the same with both methods. coef1_method1 = 0.192 and coef1_method2 = 0.059. **Why are they different? How do I obtain with emtrends the coefficient of the linear term (and how can I obtain its SE and CI)?**

Also I was surprised to see that adding the argument

```
at = list(disp = 100)
```

to the emtrends call to have

```
trends <- emtrends(model, ~ vs * am, var = "disp", max.degree=2, at = list(disp = 100))
```

changes slightly coef1_method2 even though it is still very different. **Shouldn't the slope /coef1 be the same for any disp value as it shows the change with one value change of disp?**

PS. `library(ggeffects) ggemmeans(model, c("disp[100]", "vs[0]", "am[0]"))` provides the same result as method1

Answer (score 3):

The `emtrends()` function is used for estimating slopes of trend lines. However, your calculation...

```
mpg_x100__method1 = intercept_method1 + coef1_method1 * x + coef2_method1 *x^2 # 0.85
```

Is the *predicted value* (not the slope) when `disp = 100` and `vs = am = 0`. You can verify this:

```
> emmeans(model, ~vs*am, at = list(disp=100))
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
 vs am emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 0  0   0.848 12.03 20    -24.3     25.9
 1  0  26.203  3.51 20     18.9     33.5
 0  1  27.588  3.06 20     21.2     34.0
 1  1  26.473  1.63 20     23.1     29.9

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Note that the first estimate is your 0.85.

The estimation of trends is complicated by the presence of `I(disp^2)` in the model formula, causing the trend to depend on `disp`, and not directly readable from the model coefficients. Looking at

```
> coef(model)
      (Intercept)               vs1               am1              disp         I(disp^2) 
    -1.550366e+01      6.292491e+01      6.098985e+01      1.923409e-01     -2.882756e-04 
          vs1:am1          vs1:disp          am1:disp     vs1:I(disp^2)     am1:I(disp^2) 
    -7.048372e+01     -4.733640e-01     -4.092519e-01      9.766351e-04      6.675341e-04 
     vs1:am1:disp vs1:am1:I(disp^2) 
     6.948172e-01     -2.546735e-03
```

You can tell that there are no less than 8 coefficients that involve `disp`, and the trend is a function of those 8 coefficients.

For example, at `am = vs = 0`, it involves only the first two of these 8 coefficients (indexes 4 and 5). Since the derivative of $b_4d + b_5d^2$ is $b_4 + 2b_5d$, we get:

```
> b = coef(model)
> b[4] + 2*b[5]*100
     disp 
0.1346858
```

and the answer of about 0.135 is verified with `emtrends`:

```
> emtrends(model, ~am*vs, var = "disp", at = list(disp=100))
 am vs disp.trend     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 0  0       0.135 0.0939 20  -0.0614  0.33052
 1  0      -0.141 0.0717 20  -0.2905  0.00869
 0  1      -0.143 0.0957 20  -0.3427  0.05652
 1  1      -0.234 0.0623 20  -0.3641 -0.10412

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: Thanks. My wording was a bit unclear but I was not comparing a point estimate (p.e.) to a slope but a p.e (0.85) to a p.e. (-12.5) and a slope (0.192) to a slope (0.059). Does the derivative you showed not express the change in slope of dist rather than the linear coefficient of dist?

Comment: The derivative will be a slope, not a change in slope. If you want changes in slopes, use `pairs()` or `contrast()` on the results of `emtrends()`